Question has been marked duplicate with unrelated topic
I posted the following question:
Looking for techniques or tools to add news/technical events to historical price charts
The question asks about visualizing news events on price chart time axis.
Someone persisted that my question has something to do with available data sources online. Then closed my question.
I am confused. Why my question tagged as duplicate?

Agreed this is not a duplicate of that question. Reopened.
